# How to call a batch file that is written in PHP from Java?

Tags: java, php, batch-file

I am a very new in Java. I would like to know how can I call a batch file that is written in PHP from Java.

Comment: Anything you've tried so far?

Comment: [Lots of duplicates here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=run+PHP+from+Java) too. Please always search before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is not difficult:

```
try{
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start (Here the path of your batch file)");
}catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
  ex.printStackTrace(); 
 }
```

This is Runtime mechanism of Java.

[Some more examples](http://www.coderanch.com/t/419192/java/java/Runtime-getRuntime-exec-String-command).

Comment: he said he want to run a batch file(this work for him)..